# Oracle functions - Unknown number of parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Can a function in Oracle have an unknown number of parameters?

for example: `create function sample(parameters... varchar)`

so it can call something like: `sample("A")` or `sample("A","B")` or `sample("A","B","C")`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sys.odcivarchar2list`:

```
function sample(parameters sys.odcivarchar2list)
```

And then call it by:

```
sample(sys.odcivarchar2list('A','B','C'))
```

or

```
sample(sys.odcivarchar2list('A'))
```

and so on.

Comment: for this stament: 
AND (USERNAME IN (parameters ) is this the right thing to call?

Comment: You can do this then with: `AND (USERNAME IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(parameters)))`.

Comment: how can I call this if I have different other params, like: sample(paramA varchar, parameters sys.odcivarchar2list), is this possible?

Comment: That's no problem, then just call `sample('Your input', sys.odcivarchar2list('A','B','C'))`.