# Oracle function get least value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a simple function that returns the least value passed to the function... but when running it doesn't work it just returns the same values I pass into the function 15,2,3 which should return 2... can someone help me and tell me why it doesn't work?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
function
 GET_LEAST_VALUE(in_numbers IN VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2
 IS
 vReturn varchar2(50);
 
   BEGIN
       vReturn := least(in_numbers);
     return vReturn;
   END;
```

Comment: You can just pass the individual values directly to [LEAST](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LEAST.html). You will want to make sure that the first parameter is of type NUMBER. If you need to wrap the call to LEAST and pass a single parameter containing comma-separated-values, then check [Split varchar into separate columns in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199849/split-varchar-into-separate-columns-in-oracle).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle functions - Unknown number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408757/oracle-functions-unknown-number-of-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

As commented, it can't work as you're actually passing a string to the function.

Here's one option - it splits that string into rows; `regexp_substr` returns a string (again) so - trim it first (to remove possible spaces) and apply `to_number` (otherwise you'd compare strings, and that's different from comparing numbers). Finally, apply the `min` aggregate function because `least` won't work if you passed more than a single *number* (you'd get too_many_rows error).

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_least_value (in_numbers IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  IS
  4     vreturn  VARCHAR2 (50);
  5  BEGIN
  6     WITH
  7        temp
  8        AS
  9           (    SELECT TO_NUMBER (TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (in_numbers,
 10                                                       '[^,]+',
 11                                                       1,
 12                                                       LEVEL))) val
 13                  FROM DUAL
 14            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (in_numbers, ',') + 1)
 15     SELECT MIN (val)
 16       INTO vreturn
 17       FROM temp;
 18
 19     RETURN vreturn;
 20  END;
 21  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT get_least_value ('15,2,3') result FROM DUAL;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_least_value (in_numbers IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
    w_result NUMBER ;
BEGIN
    SELECT MIN(value) INTO w_result FROM 
    json_table (
        '[' || in_numbers || ']',
        '$[*]'
        columns (
            value NUMBER PATH '$'
        )
    )
    ;
    RETURN w_result ;
END ;
/


SELECT get_least_value('4,1,9,0,-5') from dual ;


-5
```

Comment: You can even use '$[*].numberOnly()' to filter out non-number of the input array.

Comment: And with XML:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_least_value (in_numbers IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
    w_result NUMBER ;
BEGIN
    SELECT XMLQUERY( ('fn:min((' || in_numbers || '))') RETURNING content).getNumberVal() INTO W_result
    FROM dual ;
    RETURN w_result ;
END ;

Answer (score 0):

#### Why it doesn't work?

It does work as you pass in a single string and `LEAST` finds the least value when comparing that single string to nothing else so it returns that single string; which is exactly what `LEAST` is intended to do.

However, it is not what you expect it to do.

#### Why does it not do what I expect?

You are expecting `'15,2,3'` to be evaluated as a list of numbers (i.e. `LEAST(15,2,3)`) but it is not a list of numbers it is a single string literal that happens to look, to a human, like a list of numbers but, to the SQL engine, it is actually only one string value and will be evaluated as `LEAST('15,2,3')`.

#### How to fix it?

You need to either pass in multiple values via a collection (for example, the built-in `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` varray collection type):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION GET_LEAST_VALUE(
  in_numbers IN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_least NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MIN(column_value)
  INTO   v_least
  FROM   TABLE(in_numbers);

  RETURN v_least;
END;
/
```

and then call it as:

```sql
SELECT get_least_value(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(15,2,3))
FROM   DUAL;
```

or

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(get_least_value(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(15,2,3)));
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/x4KPL2uU)

Or alternatively, you need to [split the string into separate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989) and then find the minimum of those values.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done in an old way with one user defined function spliting a string by delimiter and returning an array of elements. In that case the simple plsql fuction could be like here:

```sql
create or replace Function Get_Least(P_LIST VARCHAR2, P_DELIMITER VARCHAR2 := ',') Return NUMBER AS
BEGIN
    Declare
        elements      STRING_ARRAY := STRING_ARRAY();
        least_element Number(12) := 999999999999;
    Begin
        elements := split(P_LIST , P_DELIMITER);
        For i In 1..elements.count Loop
            If To_Number(elements(i)) < least_element Then
                least_element := To_Number(elements(i));
            End If;
        End Loop;
        RETURN least_element;
    End;
END get_Least;
```

Here are the user defined type STRING_ARRAY and SPLIT() function:

```sql
create or replace TYPE STRING_ARRAY AS  
VARRAY(4000) OF VARCHAR2(1000);
/

create or replace FUNCTION split ( csvString  IN  VarChar2, delimiter  IN  VarChar2 := ',') 
                  RETURN STRING_ARRAY AS 
BEGIN
    Declare
        elements     STRING_ARRAY := STRING_ARRAY();
        CURSOR c IS
            SELECT  COL1
            FROM    (   SELECT INDX, MY_STR1, COL1_ELEMENTS, COL1
                  FROM  (   SELECT 0 "INDX", COL1 "MY_STR1", COL1_ELEMENTS, COL1
                          FROM(
                                SELECT
                                  REPLACE(COL1, delimiter || ' ', delimiter) "COL1",    
                                  Trim(Length(Replace(COL1, delimiter || ' ', delimiter))) - Trim(Length(Translate(REPLACE(COL1, delimiter || ' ', delimiter), 'A' || delimiter, 'A'))) + 1 "COL1_ELEMENTS"
                                FROM (SELECT csvString "COL1" FROM DUAL)        
                              )
                      )
                  MODEL     
                      DIMENSION BY(0 as INDX)
                      MEASURES(COL1, COL1_ELEMENTS, CAST('a' as VarChar2(4000)) as MY_STR1)
                      RULES ITERATE (1000)      --UNTIL (ITERATION_NUMBER <= COL1_ELEMENTS[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1]) -- If you don't know the number of elements this should be bigger then you aproximation. Othewrwise it will split given number of elements
                      (
                        COL1_ELEMENTS[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = COL1_ELEMENTS[0],
                        MY_STR1[0] = COL1[CV()],
                        MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = SubStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], InStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], delimiter, 1) + Length(delimiter)),
                        COL1[ITERATION_NUMBER + 1] = SubStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], 1, CASE WHEN InStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], delimiter) <> 0 THEN InStr(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER], delimiter)-1 ELSE Length(MY_STR1[ITERATION_NUMBER]) END)
                      )
                )
            WHERE INDX > 0 And INDX <= COL1_ELEMENTS;  -- And COL1 Is Not Null;
        cStr    VarChar2(1000);
        i       Number := 1;
    Begin 
        If c%ISOPEN Then CLOSE c; End If;
        OPEN c;
        LOOP
            FETCH c Into cStr;
            EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
            elements.extend;
            elements(i) := cStr;
            i := i + 1;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c;
        RETURN elements;
    End;
END split;
/
```

Test call with string containing comma separated list of numbers

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    least_one    NUMBER(3);
    Numbers_List VARCHAR2(100) := '123, 46, 756, 3, 918, 4';
Begin
    least_one := GET_LEAST(Numbers_List);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(least_one);
End;
--  
--  Result:
--
--  anonymous block completed
--  3
```

SPLIT() function could split  any string by any delimiter (including space character for splitting words in a sentence). It works with db versions without regexp too.
Example: - the same numbers separated by 'xo' - same result

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    least_one    NUMBER(3);
    Numbers_List VARCHAR2(100) := '123xo46xo756xo3xo918xo4';
Begin
    least_one := GET_LEAST(Numbers_List, 'xo');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(least_one);
End;
--  
--  Result:
--
--  anonymous block completed
--  3
```

Regards...